# I want to get Build Number, Android Version of my Android device using Java. I am using the following code:

Tags: java, android

```
public class Device {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //buildNum = Build.DISPLAY;
        System.out.println("Build Number: " + android.os.Build.DISPLAY);
        System.out.println("Model: " + android.os.Build.MODEL);
        System.out.println("Build Version: " + android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE);
    }
}
```

It gives me output as:

Build Number: null

Model: null

Build Version: null

Can anybody point out where I am ding the mistake?

Comment: Wait, youre doing this in a main method? Does this even compile/run?

Comment: write the same code in onCreate method of your launcher activity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem might be that you're querying these values from a main method.
Therefore, it might not be running on an actual Android device. Then of course there'll be no correct values.

You'll need to access these values from an Android device or it will have no Version number etc..

I doubt the code you posted runs/compiles as you posted it.